# Run cmd commands and fill it with data through Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line

I need to create an IntelliJ Maven project using Java code.
The command to create new Maven project is:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=ToolsQA -DartifactId=DemoMavenProject -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I need to write program code that runs this command through the command line.

Steps:

- run the command line
- enter to C direction
- enter the command that create new maven project.

Thanks!

[image: I tried this code, and its not workung]

[image: I get the exception:]

Comment: Please, use markdown code block instead of images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `cmd.exe` is in the `PATH`, if not, you will need to complete the fully qualified path to it. For example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"/c",
"cd \" C:\\Program Files\" ",
);
```

Actually, you don't have to use the command to switch execution path, try the directory method:

```
String initMvnProjectCommand = "mvn archetype:generate ...";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        "/c",
        initMvnProjectCommand);
builder.directory(new File("${the path you want to execute the command}"));
builder.start();
```

Comment: ok, thanks!Now after the terminal is opened I need to write into the terminal a command to execute, can you help me how to do it?

Comment: Actually, you don't have to use the command to switch execution path, try the `directory` method, eg: `builder.directory(new File("${the path you want to execute the command}"));`. Then execute `mvn` command. I added the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is not a [Windows] [command prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) emulator. Via the class methods, you set a single command to execute as well as the working directory for the command and the environment.

The following code executes the command in your question. It also sets the working directory to `C:\Users\USER`. It redirects the command output and the command error output to [System.out](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) and [System.err](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#err), respectively. It does **not** modify the [environment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment()).

I did not add `C:\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin` to my [Windows] [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable and therefore, in the below code, I use the full path to `mvn.cmd`.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\apache-maven-3.8.6\\bin\\mvn.cmd",
                                               "archetype:generate",
                                               "-DgroupId=ToolsQA",
                                               "-DartifactId=DemoMavenProject",
                                               "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart",
                                               "-DinteractiveMode=false");
        Path path = Paths.get("C:", "Users", "USER");
        File directory = path.toFile();
        pb.directory(directory);
        pb.inheritIO();
        try {
            Process proc = pb.start();
            int status = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Completed with status: " + status);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If the command completes successfully, the value of variable `status` should be 0 (zero).

Here is the output I get when I run the above code:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: C:\Users\USER
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: ToolsQA
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: ToolsQA
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: DemoMavenProject
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: ToolsQA
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: C:\Users\USER\DemoMavenProject
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.529 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-30T20:21:50+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed with status: 0
```